# How do i do this task right here?

Tags: java, arrays, string

> In a file called PositiveMinMaxAvg. java, write a class with a main method that expects all the command-line arguments to be appropriate inputs to Double.parseDouble. It should print the average of the maximum and the minimum positive arguments from the command-line arguments that, when parsed as doubles, are strictly greater than 0. If there are less than 2 numbers in the array that are greater than 0 it should produce 0. For example, let's say your arguments are -1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 5, then your answer will be (2.5 +5)/2 = 3.75 (2.5 is the minimum positive, and 5 is the maximum positive).

Here is my code btw

```
public class PositiveMinMax {
  //static double max = 0, total = 0, min, result, i;
  //static String i; 
  public static void main(String[] args) { 
    double max = 0, total = 0, min;
    min = Double.parseDouble(args[0]);
    //for(int s = 0; s < args.length; s++)
    for (String s:args) {
      double value = Double.parseDouble(s);
      //double value2 = Double.parseDouble(args[s]);
      if (max < value) {
        max = value;   
      }

      //min = Double.parseDouble(args[s]);
      if (min>value) {
      min = value; 
      } 

      

      total = min + max; 
    }
    System.out.println(total/2);
  }
}
```

I want to know what more i need to add to the code in order to solve this problem. What do i need to do in order to only get the positive minimum and maximum values on the array and not the negatives, no matter what I do, I still don't get it.

Comment: Only execute the rest of your loop when `value > 0`. You could try simplifying the problem by writing a program that only prints positive commandline args... Anyway this question doesn't seem to fit SO very well.

Comment: Please don't use images with text: you can't copy/paste text.

Comment: And if you have to use images, post the images themselves, not a link to the image: external content tend to disappear after a while.

Comment: Poor title. Rewrite to summarize your specific technical issue.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding logic is this

```
private String getMinMax(String[] args){

        double min=0;
        double max=0;
        double result=0;
        if (args.length>1) {
            for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
                String s = args[i];
                Double d = Double.parseDouble(s);
                if (d>0){
                    if (d >= max) {
                        max = d;
                        if (min==0){
                            min=max;
                        }
                    }
                    if (d < min ) {
                        min = d;
                    }
                }
            }
            result=(max+min)/2;
        }else {
            System.out.println("Give Maximum 2 agrs");
        }

        return "("+min+"+"+max+")/2="+result;
    }
```

passing value

getMinMax(new String[]{"-1.5","5.5","1.5","3.5","5","7"});

**O/P :- (1.5+7.0)/2=4.25**

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to check that you have at least two positive values, otherwise print 0:

```
public class PositiveMinMaxAvg {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double max = 0, min = Double.MAX_VALUE, count = 0;
        for (String arg : args) {
            double value = Double.parseDouble(arg);
            if (value > 0) {
                if (value > max) {
                    max = value;
                }
                if (value < min) {
                    min = value;
                }
                ++count;
            }
        }
        if (count < 2) {
            System.out.println(0);
        } else {
            System.out.println((max + min) / 2);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep track of the `count` of numbers greater than 0, in addition to `min` and `max`. Some pseudocode:

```
init min and max with appropriate values
for (String arg : args) {
  parse value
  if value > 0 -> increase count
  if value < min -> reassign min
  if value > max -> reassign max
}
if count > 1 -> print average of min and max
else -> print 0
```

As another option, you can use the [Stream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) API:

```
DoubleSummaryStatistics statistics = Arrays.stream(args)
        .mapToDouble(parse element to double)
        .filter(keep strictly positive only)
        .summaryStatistics();
if (statistics.getCount() > 1) {
  //calculate average of min and max
} else {
  System.out.println(0);
}
```